# Alternatives for Java Schedulers

Tags: java, scheduler

Following is my requirement:

On a periodical basis, a "request"  needs to be enqueued into a queue
The different parameters of the "request", the periodicity of execution, start date of execution, and the last run date  are stored in a database.

There can be few thousands of such requests in the database.

Now, I want to write a scheduler which polls the database regularly, and when the current date is equal to the "last run date" + "periodicity", the request  should be enqueued.

Please suggest the alternatives availabe for schedulers

This scheduler should be capable of running  on multiple hosts

Thanks,
Hima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)? It may well do all you need very simply. I haven't used it myself, but I've heard good things about it.

Comment: Yes. I had a look at quartz. I am just trying to evaluate other alternatives as well.